# how to extract msi from exe

Tags: windows-installer, extract

I am trying to extract an MSI from a exe the developer/vendor has made available to us.  I am running into all kinds of problems in doing this.  The vendor is rather secretive about the procedure.  In researching Microsoft' site I find that a /a switch would normally be used to extract the contents.  That does in fact unzip the files but that MSI is not a standalone installer and requires the other support files that would normally be contained in the MSI.  For that reason the MSI is a lot smaller.  The one situation creates an MSI of 23mb and requires all the other files be present to install.  I did find out from the vendor that if I use a /b switch and specify the extraction location it will extract the MSI and the size is 800mb as it should be.  I can find nothing to document this switch.

Can someone tell me why the extraction method and/or switch would extract a different size MSI and may or may not require the other install files to work?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A self extracting installer can do practically anything that it needs to extract itself, nobody here will have any hope of guessing what you need to do unless you at last can figure out what program creates the self extracting installer. Fortunately though, with self extracting installer, all the information you needed to know to extract the file will be in the file itself, you just need to know how to reverse assemble the self extracting file.

Answer (score 1):

If you spend some time in enterprise IT  you'll get your hands on thousands of installers.  You'll find that frequently the setup.exe is one of several kinds with well known switches but that most of the time it's vendor developed and there is no standard command line or documentation available.

This is one of the reasons for MSI in the first place.  Eliminate the EXE and produce a common user experience.  The problem was that MSI couldn't handle all scenarios and EXE's are sometimes still needed.